# how can I empty a mutable map (defined by val)?

Tags: scala

I define a mutable property for my object

```
object myobject{
  val myMap = mutable.Map[String,mutable.Set[String]]
  def clear {// I don't know what code I must write here for remove all key Values on myMap}
  def add(keyValue:(String,String)){//some code for add a keyValue to mymap}
}
```

Comment: Um...it's called `clear`.  An obvious choice, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: :) I am in bad mode, (I have used exactly same name for method of my object) this question can win funniest question of the month award, I don't remove it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look in the [api docs](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html)!

```
myMap.clear()
```